# Make meshes with armature (converted from B-Bones) fall onto plane in a pile

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation, parent

I'm new to blender so please bear with me–

I created a model of a large worm with a small person parented within. The person is parented to the worm and both of them are parented to bendy bones (which I rigged to be attached to regular armature).

I want the worm to fall from space as a soft object, so the 4 points (including the ends) where the worm ends all react differently to gravity WHILE keeping the small person parented within. I'm also trying to do this with minimal distortion (as would be normal if a real worm fell). [image]

I've tried creating rigid bodies and attaching them to the controls of the armature but this didn't work, the worm wouldn't fall and/or when I moved the rigid bodies it completely warped the mesh.

Would love some direction as to what physics properties I should be using and/or if this will even with with the current armature rig I have set up.

Edit: I don't know if a flocking system or gravity painting would work?